# Angular search form - show options list only when elements are found

Tags: angular

I made a search form which passes the found element to my FormControl. The filter works fine but the problem is the full list of options is always displayed and I want it to be shown only AFTER I start typing and some elements are matched and also to have the option to click on them to have them selected.

[image]

search-input.html

```
<div class="form-group row" [formGroup]="group">
  <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">{{label}}</label>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <input type="search" [(ngModel)]="model" [formControlName]="controlName" placeholder="Search text" class="form-control search-wrapper">
  </div>
</div>
<ul *ngFor="let data of options | filter: model">
  <li>{{data}}</li>
</ul>
```

search-input.ts

```
@Input() label: string;
@Input() group: string;
@Input() model: string;
@Input() controlName: string;
@Input() options: string[];
```

filter-pipe.ts

```
transform(items: any[], model: string): any[]  {
    if (!items) {
      return [];
    }
    if (!model) {
      return items;
    }
    model = model.toLocaleLowerCase();

    return items.filter(it => {
      return it.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(model);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Set breakpoint in filter I don't think its working.  Tell us, is it filtering properly?

Comment: @JohnPeters the filter is indeed working properly, as I said in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ngIf`, hide the list when the model is empty. With the condition `model.length`, we're only displaying the list when the model has at least 1 character. At that point, the filter pipe will kick in and show the filtered results.

```
<ul *ngIf="model && model.length">
  <li *ngFor="let option of options | filter: model">
    <button (click)="handleClick(option)">{{option}}</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

```
handleClick(option) {
  this.model = option;
}
```

Since `model` is a string, and [length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length) is a property that returns a number, we can assert `model.length` to be a truthy value when it is greater than zero. Otherwise, if the length is zero, it is a falsy value.

And to address the issue of model being undefined, you could initialize it to an empty string, or consider expanding the conditional check to `model && model.length`.

Comment: It works, with the exception that when I load the page the first time I get on console TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined before I'm pressing any key, and also because of this, the elements displayed  after the serachbox doesn't have any label (I'm using other form of inputs on that page). After pressing any key everything gets back to normal.

Comment: Ok, makes sense. Give this a try `*ngIf="model && model.length"`

Comment: Great, works perfectly, the only thinkg remains is to be able to select the option from the list into the searchbox because at the moment even if matches are found we cannot select then and the information can be send incomplete.

Comment: You should be able to assign a click event handler to the element inside your `<li>`. For example, using a button with click event to set the model. This will populate the search field with the user selection.

Comment: Using <li *ngFor="let data of options | filter: model" (click)="onSelect(data)">{{data}}</li>, where onSelect(data: string) {this.model = data;} doesn't works, I cannot select the elements.

Comment: Thank you, now it works as expected. Have a nice day!

Comment: That's great to hear.

Comment: One more thing, after we select the value, the list of searches must dissapear. Using a boolean flag that will be enabled on handleClick and using *ngIf on ul or button doesn't work.